# What is cookie "U" from domain ".adsymptotic.com" found on the WordPress page?

Tags: cookies

On a landing page of our WordPress site, I find a cookie "U" from domain ".adsymptotic.com" as the image below shows. Could you please let me know where this comes from because searching the project folder doesn't show results for this cookie?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from LinkedIn. It's listed here: https://www.linkedin.com/legal/l/cookie-table

Comment: Thanks, this helped figure it out.

Comment: Hi, I've a WordPress page built with DIVI builder that has multiple <title> tags as verified with its view source page. I don't find the <title> tag in the Divi builder's sections so I can remove the duplicates. Can you share your thoughts on locating the full HTML of this page https://andersonadvisors.com/how-to-structure-a-business-workshop-training/ in the WordPress admin or Divi builder?